# Django: avoiding multiple evaluations of the same expression in a template?

Tags: python, django, templates, variables

When passing an object called `widget` as part of the context to rendering a django template, I may have a method which is a bit expensive, but I want to display the result of it more than once.

Python:

```
class Widget:
   def work(self):
      # Do something expensive
```

Template

```
This is a widget, the result of whose work is {{widget.work}}.  Do
you want to save {{widget.work}} or discard {{widget.work}}?
```

Clearly I could work around this by evaluating the method once in the view code, and then passing the result in, but this seems to couple the view and the template too much.  Is there a way for the template author to stash values for re-use later in the template?  I would like to do something like this:

```
{% work_result = widget.work %}
This is a widget, the result of whose
work is {{work_result}}.  Do you want to save {{work_result}} or discard {{work_result}}?
```

Does such a construct exist in the django template language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`{% with %}`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Answer (score 3):

```
{% with work_result=widget.work %}
```

Look Django [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with) for more information

Comment: but this syntax should be correct for the current development version,